# Material Autocomplete does'nt work after adding MatInput fields dynamically but before adding it works and populates

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

The code works for the first default matInput field and populates the suggestion list during the input change however when I add new fields to the form the suggestion list does not work and stops during the input change.

```
<form
  [formGroup]="feasibilityForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(feasibilityForm.value)"
>
  <mat-form-field
    [style.width.%]="100"
    formArrayName="serviceNames"
    *ngFor="let service of serviceNames.controls; let i = index"
  >
    <mat-label> Service Activity </mat-label>
    <input
      [formControlName]="i"
      matInput
      type="text"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions"
        [value]="item.Service"
      >
        {{ item.Service }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="form-element">
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit">Primary</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The purpose is to add matInput fields dynamically to the form and autoComplete the suggestion list for each matInput field added.

```
options = [];

  feasibilityForm;
  filteredOptions;
  title = 'my-app';

  constructor(private service: MyService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.getNames();
    this.service.getLocalData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

  initForm() {
    this.feasibilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      serviceNames: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('')]),
    })

    this.feasibilityForm.get('serviceNames').valueChanges.subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log('data is ', response);
      this.filterData(response);
    })
  }

  get serviceNames() {
    return this.feasibilityForm.get('serviceNames') as FormArray;
  }

  addServiceName() {
    this.serviceNames.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
    this.getNames();
    this.filteredOptions = [];
  }

  onSubmit(value) {
    console.log(this.serviceNames.value)
  }

  filterData(enteredData) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter((item) => {
      console.log(item.Service)
      return item.Service.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(enteredData.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
    })
  }

  getNames() {
    this.service.getLocalData().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.options = response;
      this.filteredOptions = response;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is from your `filterData`. You loop through the options instead of the `enteredData`.

The reason is `enteredData` will be come an array as you add more input.

Let's go with a small example: options = ['1','2','3']

1. With 1 input: enteredData = [1] => toString returns '1'. options.indexOf('1') returns true.
2. Now you add 1 more input => enteredData = ['1','1'] (assume you enter your text into both inputs) => toString returns '1,1' => options.indexOf('1,1') which will always return -1.

Comment: You gave the half answer what about the solution for that.

Comment: what is the other half?

Comment: I want to know where I get source of input because I have multiple inputs and response inside subscription is array of strings and there is no way to relate with source of input to deal it in filterData

Comment: I'm sorry but did I read it wrong or did you just forget to mention that in your question?

Comment: Not at all but do you have any idea regarding the solution as diagnosed the problem but did not complete the solution I would be happy if you have a solution because I tried many ways.